# How to put custom input for debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, input, visual-studio-code

In Visual studio code , i dont want to give long input to my program everytime. Is there a way like in hackerearth to copy paste my input and the program will run on them.

Take this as example.What should i write in args of launch.json. I am new to vscode.[Here is my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwelE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the main() as below:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
for(int i = 1; i <argc; ++i)
std::cout<<argv[i];
return 0;
}
```

This is simple program.

[image]

You have to right-click the project, choose Properties, go to the Debugging section -- there is a box for "Command Arguments".
Specify the as "34 45 44".

You can run this again and again by mentioning it once.

Comment: i want to enter 3 variables. sorry im new i dont understand this

Comment: Provide parameters with space in between them as I have shown "34 45 44". These are three variables. Try to run my code and set the Command argument as mentioned.

Comment: @ShivamGautam below video for you if I am still not clear
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgbQCRHKV-Y