# How to convert a command line argument to an int?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, atoi

Im trying to convert the command line argument(*argv[]) to an integer using the atoi function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

This is my attempt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


int x = 0;
for ( x=0; x < argc; x++ )
{
int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        cout << x;
}
return 0;
}
```

However this returns 0 and im unsure why. Thankyou

Comment: How do you run the program? Can you rename the inner `x` to something else?

Comment: Do you actually pass any arguments to the program? And please try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of that loop. It doesn't do what you might think it does. Also please don't use the same variable name for different things in different scopes, it makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: argv[1]->argv[x]??

Comment: Note, that `atoi` returns 0, when the argument could not be converted to an integer, you probably parse some string that isn't a number at all. Use a debugger to make sure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im using visual studio so im not sure how to pass arguments with it. Noob i know

Comment: @Klaus Unfortunately that will lead to undefined behavior. The `x` in `argv[x]` will be the *uninitialized* loop-local variable `x`, not the loop iterator variable `x`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Wow, yes, x is defined again... OK, to many issues in some lines of code... yes, also it should be y = argv[x]. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702210/how-to-put-custom-input-for-debugging-in-visual-studio-code @DavidLing

Comment: Don't use the x variable twice in program.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say having the arguments you pass to your program, but there are few problems here.

1. Your loop goes from 0 to `argc`, but your inside your loop you always use `argv[1]`, if you didn't pass any arguments you're going out of bounds, because `argv[0]` is always the path to your executable.
2. `atoi` is a function from C, and when it fails to parse it's argument as an int, it returns 0, replace it with [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and you will get and execption if the conversion failed. You can catch this exception with `try/catch`, and then check the string that you tried to convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < argc; x++)
    {
        cout << argv[x];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

just prints the path to the .exe, the path is a string, it has no numbers. And as I understood from my "research" about command line arguments, you need to use your program through a command line, a terminal, to initialise the argv argument.

Link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

Also, as I understood at least, the `argv[0]` is always the path of the .exe

I hope I will be of some help, if I am mistaken at something, pls tell me where and I will correct my self by editing the answer